# Using grpc c++‘s async server api, should I add one (or more) cq per rpc method or just one cq for all service?

Tags: grpc

Using grpc c++‘s async server api, should I add one cq per rpc method or just one cq for all service?

I am taking over a grpc c++ service in my job. it use 10 completionqueue for a async service method , and yet another 20 completionqueue for another stream service method. The handling of the completionqueue is quite similar to the helloworld async service example, except that it use one thread worker per completionqueue.

Such a design is not very convenient for adding more service method. And I am thinking that refactoring it to using just one completionqueue, and dispatching the tags in the completionqueue to my own domain transactions handling thread pool.

Is it the right design pattern, or is there something better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to know the answer for your specific application is to create benchmarks with various scenarios and then compare the results from the different threading models.

Based on https://grpc.github.io/grpc/cpp/md_doc_cpp_perf_notes.html, the current recommendation is to use a pool of num_cpus threads with each thread polling over its own completion queue.

Comment: Say I have an RPC for collecting data and sending commands to server all under one Service. How can I setup so that one thread on server listens on one port and only for the command rpc. I currently have async data rpc using threadpool but when I add the command sync grpc errors about server can only have 1 asynccall. In my implementation I have 2 server objects, 2 cqs and one of the rpc calls attached. How do I implement this? My goal is to have one thread dedicated for the command rpc.

Comment: The grpc error message is assertion failed: service->server_ == nullptr && "Can only register an asynchronous service against one server."